# Evaluate $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{n \sin x}{1+n^2x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Notice that $\frac{n \sin x}{1+n^2x^2}\to 0$ pointwise.

And we have,$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{n \sin x}{1+n^2x^2}dx=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{n \sin x}{1+n^2x^2}dx+\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{n \sin x}{1+n^2x^2}dx$$

Then for $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{n \sin x}{1+n^2x^2}dx$ portion we have,
$$\left|\frac{n \sin x}{1+n^2x^2}\right|\leq\left|\frac{n}{n^2x^2}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{nx^2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{x^2}$$

And $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is integrable on $(1,\infty)$
So by the dominated convergence theorem:
$$\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{n \sin x}{1+n^2x^2}dx\to\int\limits_0^{\infty}0=0$$

But how should I do the $\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{n \sin x}{1+n^2x^2}dx$?
Appreciate your help

Comment: Often times with these problems, computing the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ is easier than computing the value for any particular $n$.  Since you ask about $\int_0^1 \frac{n\sin x}{1+n^2 x^2}\; dx$ instead of the limit, could you clarify that you really want to know the answer for fixed $n$?

Comment: @gune are you sure the portion from one to infinity will go to zero? If so I got an idea: do $F(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{n \cdot \sin (tx) dx}{1 + (nx)^2}$ and notice that $F(t) - n^2F''(t)$ is a cool function.

Comment: @JasonDeVito yes it is for a fixed n and then I will take the limit $n\to\infty$

Comment: @hellofriends Thank you. i will try that

Comment: meh it helps if you know some special values of the eliptic functions. I thought it would be more helpful than it was, sorry: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+-+n%C2%B2+y%27%27+%3D+n*%281-cos%28x%29%29%2Fx

Comment: @gune:  But, for example, in your original post, for the integral from $1$ to $\infty$, you never evaluated the integrals for fixed $n$, just the limit.  My question is whether or not you'd be happy with an answer which did the same thing when the bounds are $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes. Sure. the same thing for the bounds $(0,1)$ will be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And idea: substitute

$$x=\frac1u\implies dx=-\frac1{u^2}du\implies\int_0^1\frac{n\sin x}{1+n^2x^2}dx=\int_\infty^1-\frac{du}{u^2}\cdot\frac{n\sin\frac1u}{1+\frac{n^2}{u^2}}=$$

$$=\int_1^\infty\frac{n\sin\frac1u}{u^2+n^2}du$$

and now estimate

$$\left|\frac{n\sin\frac1u}{u^2+n^2}\right|\le\frac n{u^2+n^2}\,,\,\,\text{and}\;\int_1^\infty\frac n{n^2+u^2}du=\int_1^\infty\frac{d\left(\frac un\right)}{1+\left(\frac un\right)^2}=$$

$$=\left.\arctan\frac un\right|_1^\infty=\frac\pi2-\arctan\frac1n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac\pi2$$

Which means your integral is bounded above...

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The change fo variable $u=nx$ gives

$$
\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin(u/n)}{1+u^2}\,du
$$

The integrand is dominated by $\frac{1}{1+u^2}$ which is integrable. Then, by dominated convergence
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^\infty_0\frac{n\sin x}{1+n^2x^2} =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin(u/n)}{1+u^2}\,du=
\int^\infty_0\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin(u/n)}{1+u^2}\,du=0
$$
for $\sin(u/n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ for all $u$.